# Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

```
Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/display_import.lib.php#371: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Import',
array,
)
./libraries/display_import.lib.php#456: PMA_getHtmlForImportOptionsFormat(array)
./libraries/display_import.lib.php#691: PMA_getHtmlForImport(
string '5de53ad1bdb35',
string 'database',
string 'laxie_magento',
string '',
integer 209715200,
array,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
)
./db_import.php#43: PMA_getImportDisplay(
string 'database',
string 'laxie_magento',
string '',
integer 209715200,
)
./index.php#53: include(./db_import.php)
```

Getting this error on Import tab of **phpMyAdmin** and below are the server details

> Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
>  Server type: MySQL
>   Server version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 - (Ubuntu)
>  Protocol
>   version: 10
>  Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Answer (score 33):

This fixed my issue:

Import/Export issues
If you are also getting an error Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551 under import and export tabs:

Backup plugin_interface.lib.php

```
sudo cp /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php.bak
```

Edit plugin_interface.lib.php

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php
```

Press `CTRL + W` and search for `if (! is_null($options) && count($options) > 0) {`

If not found, try search for `if ($options != null && count($options) > 0)`

Replace with `if (! is_null($options) && count((array)$options) > 0) {`

Save file and exit. (Press `CTRL + X`, press `Y` and then press ENTER)

Comment: Great this worked fine. Although it seems a bit hacky to just cast a empty variable to an array. I'd really like to know, what causes this error. But it's fine for now. Thanks a bunch @piyush-nath

Comment: If CTRL + W doesn't work (SSH in browser or such) you can CTRL + _ and go to line 551.

Answer (score 3):

Just run this command line in terminal and come back to PhpMyAdmin.

```
sudo sed -i "s/|\s*\((count(\$analyzed_sql_results\['select_expr'\]\)/| (\1)/g" /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```